# Object doesn't support property or method 'includes' on IE 11

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer, polyfills

Am using `use-http` package in react application with the following polyfills

- whatwg-fetch
- abortcontroller-polyfill
- url-search-params-polyfill

The app also has babel configuration to handle corejs.

When I use the console, I can declare and assign an array which later I apply `includes` on it, works fine.

[image: Workign includes on array]

But when I run the app, I get the error **Object doesn't support property or method 'includes' on IE 11**. As I debug, I put a breakpoint, then I use the array which fails on on the console, and I receive the error. I have tried explicitly to use `core-js` package as well but still does not solve the issues.
[image: the array which throws error on includes]

I do not understand the inconsistency, why when I declare an array `includes` works fine but when running the app, the same function does not.

Comment: For testing purposes, can you try to add `import 'core-js/es6/string';` at the start of `index.js`. Also, include the `import 'react-app-polyfill/ie11';` in your project and again try to run the project. See if it helps to fix the issue.

Comment: I experimented with a mixture of packages, including your suggestion, unfortunately, did not work. But what finally worked, was installing `core-js` and upgrading from corejs 2 to 3 `npm i --save-dev core-js@3 @babel/runtime-corejs3` (babel config). After the upgrade, I added `import 'core-js/stable'` at the entry file and this solved the problem. The configuration for babel I got it from https://alexbogovich.com/blog/core-js/

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution to the issue. I suggest you post your solution as an answer for this thread and try to mark your own answer as an answer to this question after 48 hrs when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The combination of the following three imports worked in the entry file.

```
import "whatwg-fetch";
import "abortcontroller-polyfill";
import "core-js/stable";
```

I still have not managed to configure this through webpack however, it solves the issue I had with IE.

Comment: Have you tried including the specific includes in the entry of your build 
{
  entry: {
    main: ["core-js/features/array/includes", "./src/app.js"],
  },
  ..
}